# Скрипт на ходячего человека который сжигает калорий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можете описать процесс на js или jquery, как сделать счетчик времени и каллорий& Путь укажите я сделаю. Просто когда сам сначала пишу тут логика хромает сильно.

Мол пока вы были на сайте 5 минут он прошел 0.5 км и сжег 20 каллорий.
Так же на чем сделать анимацию ходячего человека ? svg или gif?

Comment: 1. Сначала фиксировать секуны пребывания. Или время когда первый раз зашли, и переводит время в секунды пребывания (тут по-разному можно)  Потом домножить секунды на коефициент в каллории и коефициент в киллометры. 2. Анимация - скачайте готовую.

Comment: Спасибо! вам за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование анимации в принципе не играет роли на данном этапе, и можете сделать как душе угодно.

В цикле используются секунды, но если исчисление идет в минутах, то просто домножить счетчик в setIntervalна 60

```js
var count = 0;
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');

setInterval(function() {
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = `Он провел на сайте ${count} минут и сжег ${count*4} калорий`;
}, 5000);
```

```html
<span id="counter">Он провел на сайте 0 минут и сжег 0 калорий</span>
```

Comment: а как count секунды перевести в минуты что бы нарастали ?

Comment: вам надо, чтобы были минуты или минуты + секунды?

Comment: Да было бы хорошо если бы время переходило в минуты после) ведь человек в среднем 5 минут может на сайте провести в секундах это будет слишком круто выглядеть) минуты демократичнее ) но если 60000 там ставить то тогда коунтер не появляется до того как =1 не будет то есть минуту нету блока(

Comment: Поправил, поместил дефолтное значение с нулями в html, а после истечения минуты значение перезапишется на новое.

Comment: я нашел свой жесткий диск на днях закину сюда готовый пример)